# Converting EC2 instance from instance-store root device to EBS root device

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a running 32-bit Windows EC2 instance whose root device is of type instance-store. I would like to bundle it, create an AMI, and then launch a new EC2 instance from that AMI, but change its root device to type EBS.
I can't find a way to do that in the AWS console, nor can I find documentation telling me I can't. 
Is this possible, and if so, what tool can I use to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an EBS root instance from your windows instance, for that you need to do the following steps.

1. Create an EBS volume with the desired size, mount it to running instance
2. Use some kind of cloning tool for cloning your windows disk contents to the EBS volume
3. Unmount EBS volume
4. Create a snapshot of the EBS volume
5. Use the EC2 command line tools to create a new AMI based on the snapshot, you can see an example of that in [this](http://coderslike.us/2009/12/07/amazon-ec2-boot-from-ebs-and-ami-conversion/) post (just follow the last step to register the snapshot)